# Trying to use webpack in my react app. Getting a "error Command failed with exit code 2."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, css-loader

I have been trying to follow a couple of tutorials to install webpack so i can get more customized packages loaded into my react app.

this is my package json file

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.5",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.11",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "web-dev-server": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "npm run build&&gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "homepage": "https://jdiperi88.github.io",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

this is my webpack.config file

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.png$/, 
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.jpg$/, 
        loader: "file-loader" 
      }

    ]
  },
};
```

here is my .babelrc

```
/* 
    ./.babelrc
*/  
{
    "presets":[
        "es2015", "react"
    ]
}
```

This is a screenshot of my file structure and error messages.
[image]

extension of the top screenshot
[image]

Basically I have been trying to build a portfolio and css is being rendered quite different in each browser. It is even being rendered different within the same browser when I deploy it on github pages and when I run it on the local host. So any css solutions to remedy this problem would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message "error Command failed with exit code 2" is just telling you that something went wrong when the command (`webpack`) was running.

In the output above that message, there are 4 'real' error messages.

The first three error messages say that your `App.js` file is trying to import files that don't exist.

The last error says that Webpack doesn't know what to do with a `.tff` file. As that message suggests, you'll need another loader to handle `.tff` files. You need to add `{ test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }` to your loader config. See [this issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/38) for more info.

Comment: I added that line and it worked for the tff error, but those 3 component files exist. So i dont understand why that error is coming up. They are all imported into app.js. How would I go about solving that issue?

Comment: The `App.js` file is certainly importing them, but webpack is saying those files don't exist. Check the `src` folder (which is where webpack thinks they should be).

Comment: yeah, but when i do yarn start, those three components render and the site works. The three components are in the ./src/components/(Header,Footer,Index) and app.js is in the './src'. This is what I am confused about. Appreciate the help btw.

Comment: Do the files have `.js` at the end of their name? Very strange that it semi-works. Is the Github repo public?

Comment: it was jsx at the end of those three components smh. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Comment: Do you happen to know how to make it render the app? When i build the webpack and it produces the bundle.js, it doesnt actually run the bundle.js, it brings me to the root directory when i go to localhost:8080 and i can see a variety of folders that were included in the webpack. First time trying to use this thing, so a bit of a noob.

Comment: You'll want to run that bundle file in an HTML page. There's a Webpack plugin that can generate HTML files for you: [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin). Or just manually make an HTML file and link to the bundle with a `<script>` element. Also, since you're using react, you might look into [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)